# Python pass variable to imported module at "compilation" time

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-module

I'm trying to create an object from a custom class with a decorator in it.
Then I need to use the decorator of that object to create a bunch of functions in a different file.
I found the solution of using builtins online but it feels a bit hacky and makes my lsp spit out a bunch of errors.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a better solution.

This is my file structure:

```
main.py
mylib
├── A.py
└── B.py
```

main.py

```py
import builtins

from mylib.A import A

a = A("This is printing in the decorator")
builtins.FOO = a
import mylib.B as B

B.foo()
B.poo()
```

A.py

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, _message):
        self.message = _message
    def our_decorator(self, func):
        def function_wrapper():
            print(self.message)
            func()
        return function_wrapper
```

B.py

```py
import builtins

@builtins.FOO.our_decorator
def foo():
    print("foo")

@builtins.FOO.our_decorator
def poo():
    print("poo")
```

I don't want to change the file structure if it can be avoided.

Comment: Why not create an instance of `A` in `B.py` and use that as your decorator? It's not clear why you need an instance in the first place or why you want to pass one around like this

Comment: This is a very stripped down version of the problem. I need to leave the instance A in main for other reasons that I didn't recreate in the example.

Comment: Does this instance of `A` get passed any arguments in main? Without any more information about what it contains or why it needs to be in main your question is confusing. The decorator doesn't even do anything?

Comment: Yes, I need to create A in main to pass it parameters. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You're right: this feels very hacky. What problem are you trying to solve that you think something like this is the solution to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using builtins to have a magically created decorator is indeed hacky.

An alternative would be to patch the functions in B from main. It is slightly cleaner (and linters should not complain) because the B module has no longer to be aware of the decorator:

main.py:

```
from mylib.A import A

a = A()

import mylib.B as B

# decorate here the functions of the B module
B.foo = a.our_decorator(B.foo)
B.poo = a.our_decorator(B.poo)

B.foo()
B.poo()
```

A.py is unchanged...

B.py:

```
def foo():
    print("foo")

def poo():
    print("poo")
```

As only one version of a module exists in a process, you can even use the functions of B from a third module, provided:

- either it is imported after the decoration
- or it only imports the module name (`import mylib.B as B`) and not directly the functions (`from mylib.B import foo`)